# Fluid login form with different transparency of background holder

Tags: html, css, svg, transparency, fluid-layout

I wanted to know how to create fluid layout for this: I have form holder which is placed in middle of screen. Background of this holder is white, but on top left side is transparent triangle. I have created this in combination with SVG graphic and background property. I found this solution isn't the best and I have some problems with creating fluid layout for this. Please, look at code and suggest if you have some ideas.

[Here is picture](http://www.evernote.com/shard/s241/sh/8e583e8b-7e2f-4e6d-986c-07e94166d3a1/8707692d02c0dd0569d22901d6fb87e2) how it should look like.

HTML:

```
<body id="login">

<div class="container">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <div class="red-line"></div>
    <p class="email-sent">Your password reset email has been sent.</p>
    <section class="login">
        <div class="login-header">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="assets/logo_menu_white.png" alt="" class="login-logo"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="login-form-holder">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email address" class="input-login email-address">
            <input type="passowrd" placeholder="Create password" class="input-login create-password">
            <a href="forgot-password.html" class="forgot-password">FORGOT PASSWORD?</a><br>
            <button class="btn-login">LOGIN</button>
        </div>
    </section>
    <p class="new-customer">New customer? <a href="signup.html">SIGN UP</a></p>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#login, #signup, #forgot-password {
    background: url('../assets/main.png');
    background-size: cover;
}

#login .container, #signup .container, #forgot-password .container {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

section.login, section.signup, section.forgot-password-section {
    max-width: 490px;
    min-height: 490px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;

}

.login-header, .signup-header {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url('../assets/login_bg.svg') no-repeat top center;
}

.login-form-holder, .signup-form-holder {
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    top: 143px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}

section.login, section.forgot-password-section {

}

#login .login-logo, #signup .login-logo, #forgot-password .login-logo {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#login h1, #signup h1, #forgot-password h1 {
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #fff;
}

#login .email-sent {
    color: #c3c3c3;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    display: none;
}

#login .red-line, #signup .red-line, #forgot-password .red-line {
    width: 150px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
}

#login .new-customer, #signup .new-customer, #forgot-password .new-customer {
    margin-top: 60px;
    color: #fff;
}

.new-customer a {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ff204a;
}

.header a, .new-customer a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
}

#login .input-login, #signup .input-login, #forgot-password .input-login {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: none;
    color: #b5b5b5;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #dbdbdb;
    width: 100%;
    text-indent: 45px;
    padding: 25px 0px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

#login .input-login:focus, #signup .input-login:focus, #forgot-password .input-login:focus {
    outline: none;
}

#login .email-address, #signup .your-name, #signup .email-address, #forgot-password .email-address {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#login .email-address, #signup .email-address, #forgot-password .email-address {
    background: url('../assets/email_address_grey.svg') no-repeat;
    background-size: auto 30px;
    background-position: left center;
}

#login .create-password, #signup .create-password {
    background: url('../assets/password_grey.svg') no-repeat;
    background-size: auto 30px;
    background-position: left center;
}

#signup .your-name {
    background: url('../assets/your_name_grey.svg') no-repeat;
    background-size: auto 30px;
    background-position: left center;
}

#login .forgot-password, #signup .forgot-password {
    text-align: right;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #ff204a;
}

#login .forgot-password:hover, #signup .forgot-password:hover {
    color: #de1c40;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#signup .agree-terms {
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    color: #5b5b5b;
}

.agree-terms a {
    color: #ff204a;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ff204a;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.agree-terms a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#forgot-password .remark {
    clear: both;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    line-height: 1.8;
}
```